# Laravel 5 unit testing :Fatal error: Stack overflow

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5

Im getting following error while running simple unit test in larval5

Laravel 5 unit testing :Fatal error: Stack overflow in /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php on line 1249

using nginx , hhvm, centos , laravel5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !.When http request not found the route file it throws that error .